# PostgreSQL replication strategies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, replication

Right now we are using PostgreSQL 8.3 (on Linux) as a database backend to our Ruby on Rails web application.

Considering that on PostgreSQL database we actively use row level blocking and PL/PGSQL, what can we employ to secure our data -- I mean tools, packages, scripts, strategies -- to successfully replicate the database and build multi-master combination?

I will appreciate master-slave suggestions as well.

For example, if I put several application servers running Apache/Ruby to achieve higher performance and at the end deploy several database servers, is there any way to build multi-master replication in PostgreSQL?

Right now we use PostgreSQL WAL mechanism to backup data to file system.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few tools for master-slave (and master-multislave) scenarios, usually trigger-based. [Slony-I](http://slony.info/) has already been mentioned (is stable and solid, but a bit difficult to operate). People having problems with Slony-I wrote
[Londiste](https://developer.skype.com/SkypeGarage/DbProjects/SkyTools#head-82de8ec3ed4ef158df36d038998a1bee67b0cbe3) (by Skype team) and [PyReplica](http://www.nsis.com.ar/public/wiki/PyReplicaEn). Bah, and I just spotted 
[Mammoth](https://projects.commandprompt.com/public/replicator) has been open-sourced

For multimaster there is [Bucardo](http://bucardo.org/) (note: it is not that polished)
or commercial offerings - for example by [Continuent](http://www.continuent.com) or [CyberTec](http://www.postgresql.at/).

Answer (score 7):

If you haven't already, I'd suggest a look at the [High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/high-availability.html) chapter of the PostgreSQL manual. It gives a clear overview of the available techiques and their features.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, [Bucardo](http://bucardo.org/) is really good and stable, in comparison to the others here. It is as polished as can be a Perl-based replication system, and supports master-slave as well as multi-master replication, with interesting conflict resolution concepts.

If you need simple master-slave rep I'd recommend Londiste, but for the multi-master needs, Bucardo is the only acceptable solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I though [Postgres-R](http://www.postgres-r.org/) looked promising, however, its still  in development.

It was supposedly stabilised and purported to be a potential for integration with the standard issue, but its yet to come to fruition.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but there is a new open source software for asynchronous master-master replication of PostgreSQL (also works for MySQL):
[rubyrep](http://www.rubyrep.org)

Focus is on easy setup.
Disclosure: I wrote it.

Comment: Its not as simple as it looks, however.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be very actively maintained any more, which is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [slony](http://www.slony.info/).

Answer (score 0):

PGCluster looks promising - we use it in limited situations without much problems.

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgcluster/